# Where can I find sample DMARC failure reports?

Tags: email, dmarc

I want to automate ingestion of DMARC failure reports, both aggregate and forensic. Unfortunately, I don't have a mailbox set up to collect them yet. Does anyone know where I can find sample DMARC failure reports, so I can get scripting?

Comment: you mean, the XML format and the many DMARC parsers out there? https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dmarc+parse&type=

Comment: There are [several questions on this site](https://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+dmarc+report) which include DMARC reports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching a few articles where the format of the reports are shown.

For example this image shows the image of Aggregate reports:
[image]

Articles:
 - https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc/details/what-do-dmarc-reports-look-like
 - https://www.validity.com/blog/how-to-read-your-first-dmarc-reports-part-1/
 - https://www.validity.com/blog/how-to-read-your-first-dmarc-reports-part-2/